# What is this font, please?

Tags: fonts, packages, fontspec, math-fonts

I found this note on the internet, does anyone know what the font is in it (and how to use it in latex), thanks

[image]

Comment: This is Minion Pro, which you can find by checking the properties of the document in your pdf viewer.

Comment: @close voters I picked the wrong one :( the canonical is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture.

Comment: @Marijn But the math font is not Minion Math, right? (Maybe MnSymbol?)

Comment: @mickep according to the pdf properties the math is Computer Modern.

Comment: @Marijn Ah, thanks.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you!